# How to customize display Text in date-box Angular?

Tags: angular, datebox, devextreme-angular

I'm working on an Angular project with DevExtreme.
Many DevExtreme components support template to customize how they are shown.
I want to customize the display text of a dx-date-box component similar to the other components.

Comment: You need to show your attempt before someone can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [displayFormat](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDateBox/Configuration/#displayFormat) option, like in this example: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DateBox/Formatting/Angular/Light/.